# Javascript function with no arguments and changing return values

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to write a function in Javascript that will take no arguments, but produce a different (predictable) output each time. I'll be using it for testing, so I need to be sure that I can predict the outputs, meaning that using `Date.now()` will not work. I'm thinking about using a seeded RNG (or PRNG), but I'm wondering if there are any alternate solutions.

Edit: the function must be self contained, no variables or data outside the scope of the function.

Comment: *"but I'm wondering if there are any alternate solutions"* I don't think so. If you need predictable outputs, you need to be able to provide a seed.

Comment: How about color values that increment the R, G, B values?

Answer (score 0):

Just modify a variable in a wider scope.

```js
var my_counter = 0;

function count() {
  return ++my_counter;
}

console.log(count());
console.log(count());
console.log(count());
console.log(count());
console.log(count());
console.log(count());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a randomly seeded number solution that maps to whatever results you wish to return. That way you can keep it contained within the function.

OR have an array of results that can be returned and simply increment an index (with a modulus so that the index wraps back to the start again) and return the result at the indexed value. Something like...

```
var index = 0;
var results = [ "x", "y", "z" ];

function test() {
    var value = results[index];
    index = (index++) % results.length;
    return value;
}
```

So, the function will keep looping through the x, y and z results. You can set as many predictable results as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Since via closure any function can hold state (say, your counter), you could generate any arbitrary-but-fixed data array (like, a string with the digits of Pi) and return always the next value:

```
var getArbitraryValue = (function () {
    var i = 0;

    var arbitraryValue = Math.PI.toString();

    return function () {
        // you may want to reset the index here, once your string runs out
        return arbitraryValue.charAt(i++);
    }
} ());
```

Repeating calls to getArbitraryValue will return the digits of Pi.

Comment: Any idea how to do this without expression closures? They're not supported by my version of JS.

Comment: As far as I understand, Expression Closures are functions without brackets, and I don't use that here. So what do you mean? If you mean the `(function () { ... } ())` syntax, you could also use the `apply` method: `var getArbitraryValue = function () { ... }.apply(this);`

Comment: Or if you can't use anonymous functions: `var getArbitraryValue = (function test() {
 var i = 0;

 var arbitraryValue = Math.PI.toString();

 function ret() {
  return arbitraryValue.charAt(i++);
 }
  
  return ret;
} ());`

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun use case for ES2015 generators and iterators, if you don't mind involving babel:

```
function* mygenerator() {
  let i = 0;
  while(true){
    yield i++
  }
}
const generator = mygenerator();
const noArgsDifferentResult = () => generator.next().value;

console.log(noArgsDifferentResult()); // 0
console.log(noArgsDifferentResult()); // 1
console.log(noArgsDifferentResult()); // 2
```

Try it out in the Babel live parser https://babeljs.io/repl/